# loadNibNamed in swift should be return Singleton object

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, singleton

I want to load Nib (Custom View a subclass of UIView) but the object should be singleton. I am using below code for doing same on Objective C, but now I am writing code in Swift 2.2

Can any one help me to convert this code in Swift or any other approach for doing this.

```
+(LoaderView *)sharedInstance;
{
    static LoaderView * _sharedCommonInstance;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!_sharedCommonInstance)
        _sharedCommonInstance = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        return _sharedCommonInstance;
    }
}
```

My try

```
class var sharedInstance: LoaderView {
       struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: LoaderView? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? LoaderView
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
```

but by this approach app is crashing, Please check my screenshot[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
class LoaderView {
static let sharedCommonInstance = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as UIView

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches. You can try these

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LoaderView: UIView {

    class var sharedInstance: LoaderView {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: LoaderView? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? LoaderView
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    //approach 2
    class var sharedInstanceA: LoaderView {
        struct Static {
            static let instance = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoaderView", owner: LoaderView.self, options: nil)[0] as! LoaderView
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    //approach 3
    static let sharedInstanceB = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoaderView", owner: LoaderView.self, options: nil)[0] as! LoaderView

}
```

What I called in ViewDidLoad from a ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        print(LoaderView.sharedInstance)
        print(LoaderView.sharedInstanceA)
        print(LoaderView.sharedInstanceB)
}
```

The console printed

[image: output]

Remember set "LoaderView" class in xib file

[image]

You also can reference here http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Comment: I have already tried these all approaches but nothing working.In 1 approach there is some syntax errors, and in approach 2 and 3 self is not accessible in struct

Comment: Could you post the syntax errors here for further investigation?

Comment: UINib(
                nibName: "Toast",
                bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()
                ).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as? Toast

This line returning nil

Comment: Could you try again with this : NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as as? LoaderView

Comment: this is also returning nil

Comment: I have also updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: You got that because of optional variable "instance" returned "nil", which occurred unexpectedly. Because "Static.instance!" is defined as implicitly unwrapped optional that should return a value. Please check again to ensure that "NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Toast", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? Toast" always returns valid value.